# What is a "real"?

Tags: c#

In my assignment, one of the instructions says: "Create a class that implements a string to hold the infix version of a math problem. A real to hold the correct answer. A real to hold the user's answer, and a boolean to represent if the problem is correct or not."

My program is to be a WPF program that would have 4 text boxes. 1st box is to show a list/stack of the equation to answer, 2nd box is to show the list/stack of equations with the right answer, 3rd box is to show the list/stack of the equations with the wrong answer, and the last box is to let the user input their answer. I thought about setting the user's input answer as an int, but seeing that I need to set it as a "real", I don't understand.

Comment: I'm guessing it's short for "[real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number)", i.e. a floating-point non-complex number, which we normally use a `double` for (as a normally-good-enough approximation)

Comment: Agree.. this is a badly formulated instruction. Real stems from Pascal language. When WPF is required, C# is the right choice. Float, double or decimal. I think the answer is ok. Depends how many decimals you need, most programmers use double for math problems, because the library is also in double.

Comment: badly? "real number" is a secondary school math's term

Comment: Always try Google before coming here!

Answer (score 3):

A real number is most likely what they are looking for. As a 'real' isn't a type in c#.

You could use `float`, `double`, or `decimal` depending upon the requirements of what you need it to do.

Real number doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types